# Include leading zeros when using LEFT() function

Tags: excel, padding

I am trying to grab the first two characters of a cell in excel. The cell I am trying to grab from is formatted to include padding of zeros for 6 characters (e.g. "12345" = "012345", "123" = "000123").

To grab the 2 first characters I am using the `LEFT` function (e.g. `LEFT(A1, 2)`)

The problem I am having is that the LEFT function ignores the padded zeroes, taking the first 2 non-padded numbers.

```
A1 = 012345 -> LEFT(A1, 2) = 12
A2 = 301345 -> LEFT(A2, 2) = 30
A3 = 002345 -> LEFT(A3, 2) = 23
```

Is there a way to make the left function include the padded numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface the numbers with a single quote or style to cell to be text first. You can also do things like A2=TEXT(A1,"00000") that will fix A2's content to a fixed length of 5 digits. Then do the LEFT off that.. So LEFT(TEXT(A1,"00000"),2) would possibly help you too.

Comment: Thanks! I used `=LEFT(TEXT(A2,"000000"),2)` and it worked like a charm.